# Correct plural form of "hoof"

Tags: grammatical-number

My research has shown that *hoofs* and *hooves* are correct plural forms of *hoof*.  That being said, which is preferable?  Which came first in the English language?

Comment: It looks like hoofs has been the preferred spelling until about 1975. Now they're about equal: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hoofs%2Chooves&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: As for the "f" sounding like a "v", you only have to look at the two English words "off" and "of" where the former has the "f" sound and the latter has the "v" sound. For more examples just look to the Welsh language!

Answer (score 10):

The Old English word was *hof*; its plural *hofas* would have been pronounced with a *v* sound—[hoːvas]. *Hoofs* may be older by spelling, but *hooves* is probably the older pronunciation. This is backed up by the Middle English spellings *houes* and *hooves*, pronounced [hoːvəs]. So you can make an equally compelling case for each.

I like *hooves*, *elves*, *dwarves*, &c. but it’s a matter of personal preference.

Comment: OK, now I'm intrigued, if you have the time, can you give us some more on why _hofas_ would have been pronounced [hoːvas]? Is that how the _f_ was pronounced? When would this be?

Comment: @terdon: In Old English, the unvoiced *f*, *s*, and *þ* (unvoiced th) were pronounced *v*, *z*, and *ð* (voiced th) between vowels or voiced consonants. *hof* is a strong noun, so its plural ending is *-as* in the nominal case, and that rule comes into play. The earliest evidence for this phenomenon is somewhere in the latter part of the Early Old English period, around the year 900. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) has a good table of information on the various sound changes that occurred over the history of Old and Middle English.

Comment: Thanks, I find these things quite fascinating, I really need to hang out on linguistcs.se more.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you can see in [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hoofs,%20hooves&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *hoofs* is much older but has steadily been losing ground. *Hooves* seems to be the most common version today and has been for the past few decades:

[image]

The result is pretty much the same when comparing *horse's hoofs* to *horse's hooves* so it is not an issue of *hoofs* being used as a verb (as in *he hoofs it*). The pattern is also essentially the same for [American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horse%27s%20hoofs,horse%27s%20hooves&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) and [British](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horse%27s%20hoofs,horse%27s%20hooves&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) English so it seems safe to assume that the variant *hooves* entered the language around the 1920s and has been gaining ground ever since.

Comment: Extending the graph to 2008 as @user814064 did shows _hoofs_ making a comeback though.

Comment: That does look suspiciously like **Google Books** coming on line though, with 75+ year old usages.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens you mean the 'comeback'? I guess that would make sense.

Comment: I have noticed a few instances recently of N-Grams showing resurgences of outdated phrases over the past 10 years, and I think this is a common factor. It sort of limits usefulness of N-Grams.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I generally take N-Grams results after 2000 with an even bigger pinch of salt as for those over the last couple of centuries, as there are some very implausible spikes in the 2000-2008 period that suggests that what is reflected is the quality of data rather than any underlying trend.

Comment: @JonHanna I wonder if that is why the default end date for N-Gram searches is 2000

Comment: @Kevin I'm pretty sure it is.